# Retrieving top terms query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am using Elasticsearch 1.1.0 and trying to retrieve the top 10 terms in a field called `text`

I've tried the following, but it instead returned all of the documents:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "facets": {
    "text": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "text",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

the following is an example of the result that is returned:

```
    {
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {


"total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
    "total": 2747, 
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
    {
    "_index": "index_name",
    "_type": "type_name",
    "_id": "621637640908050432",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
    "metadata": {
    "result_type": "recent",
    "iso_language_code": "en"
    },
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "created_at": "Thu Jul 16 11:08:57 +0000 2015",
    .
    .
    . 
    .
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
GET /index_name/type_name/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "facets": {
    "text": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "text",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It also returned all the documents.

Comment: `"size": 0` does forbid returning any documents, just the facets. So, I don't know what you mean by `returned all the documents`? Give an example output of what you meant

Comment: Hm. Weird. I've updated the query. Give it a try again.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use `facets`. They are deprecated. Even though you use OLD version of Elasticsearch, switch to aggregations. Quoting documentation:

> Faceted search refers to a way to explore large amounts of data by
>   displaying summaries about various partitions of the data and later
>   allowing to narrow the navigation to a specific partition.
>
> In Elasticsearch, facets are also the name of a feature that allowed
>   to compute these summaries. facets have been replaced by aggregations
>   in Elasticsearch 1.0, which are a superset of facets.

Use this query instead:

```
POST /your_index/your_type/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs" : {
    "text" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "text",
        "size" : 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will work fine